# javax.mail: Attachments arrive blank or corrupted

Tags: spring, email, encoding, multipart, javax

I have a problem with javax.mail. I have a ArrayList of MultipartFile coming from a web service, and I have to add to email as attachments. Here the source:

mailMessage.setSubject(subject);
        mailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));

```
    if (attacchments != null && attacchments.size() > 0) {

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();     
        messageBodyPart1.setText(text);   

        for(MultipartFile attachment : attacchments){

            DataSource datasource = new  ByteArrayDataSource(attachment.getInputStream(), attachment.getContentType()); 
            MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            attachmentPart.setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT);
            attachmentPart.setHeader("Content-Type", attachment.getContentType());
            attachmentPart.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "Base64"); 

            attachmentPart.setFileName(MimeUtility.encodeText(attachment.getName() + ".pdf"));
            attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(datasource));

            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);
            multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
        }
        mailMessage.setContent(multipart);

        mailMessage.saveChanges();
    }

    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();
    transport.connect(SMTPServer, 465, user, password);
    transport.sendMessage(mailMessage, mailMessage.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
```

I have no exceptions, the email arrives correctly with content text, the attachment arrive too. If it is a txt file all right, if it is an image it arrives corrupted, if it is a pdf file it arrives totally blank (but with the correct number of pages). Furthermore the file arrived has a size greater than original (e.g. 100 kb for 70 kb). Have you any idea about this?

Thank you in advance